# Android intent to open video with raw resource?

Tags: android, video, android-activity, android-intent

Does anyone know of an intent I can use to open a raw mp4 resource in the phone's video player? I tried this code:

```
    Uri video = Uri.parse( "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video );
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(video, "video/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

This threw an ActivityNotFoundException, however this has worked for me when the URI was the sdcard and the video was located there.  Does anyone know how I can use the above code with a resource file in my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other apps can't access your resources. You'll need to create a ContentProvider, or store the data in a place accessible to anyone (either SD card, or in a public folder in your local storage).

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Can you make a content provider which can return a video?

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to store the file on the file system. Content providers are useful for databases.

Comment: What if I want to include the videos with my app though, would I transfer it from the resources to the file system? Is there a better way?

Comment: Also how can another app have access to your apps part of the file system?  I thought that was blocked off?  Isn't /data/data/com.your.app/ a private directory?

Comment: Not if you use `openFileOutput` with `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`.