# How to play a video file on Android with Delphi XE5 from a private dir

Tags: android, delphi, video, delphi-xe5

I am with Delphi XE5 and Firemonkey building an Android app that is to play video files:
This code is working:

```
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  fChosenVideo : string;
  Data: Jnet_Uri;


  fChosenVideo := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(TPath.GetSharedDownloadsPath) + 'myVideo.mp4';
  Data := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString('file://' + fChosenVideo));
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  Intent.setDataAndType(Data, StringToJString('video/mp4'));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
```

But I really want it to play from the apps private folder:

```
  fChosenVideo := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(TPath.GetDocumentsPath)+'myMovie.mp4';
```

I have found that I should be able to set permissions so external apps can read the file by setting MODE_WORLD_READABLE somewhere, but I cannot seem to grasp how to accomplish this.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Jens Fudge

Answer (score 1):

your question is answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139903)
after you put your file to a public place you may want to change the attribs like MODE_WORLD_READABLE.
in delphi you use something like this for doing this:

```
var
  xFas: TFileAttributes;
begin
  sFnExt = '/sdcard/file1.mp4';
  xFas:= System.IOUtils.TFile.GetAttributes(sFnExt);
  Include(xFas,TFileAttribute.faOthersRead);
  System.IOUtils.TFile.SetAttributes(sFnExt,xFas);
```