# Android intent to video player to play video in res/raw file

Tags: android, video

I am new in Android and I have problem with playing video using stack android video player. I search answer everywhere but don't find it.

My code is:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.lp);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setPackage(getPackageName());
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

It doesn't work and application crash. What is wrong. Is it depend to smartphone model? My smartphone model is THL 5000, Android 4.4.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize like this. This worked for me

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/file_name");
```

Comment: It shows me ActivityNotFoundException:

'No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://example.qqq.com.dcp/raw/lp.mp4 typ=video/* pkg=example.qqq.com.dcp }'

Comment: if(getContext().getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null) {}

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately other apps (Android intents) can't access your resources.

1. You'll need to create a ContentProvider, or store the data in a place accessible to anyone (either SD card, or in a public folder in your local storage) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139903/4291264).
2. An other solution could be, to use the Android [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html). The MediaPlayer can run audio and video files, where the source file is located on your device, from a URL or from your resources. To play a video file you need to combine it with SuffaceView. [Here](http://o7planning.org/en/10487/android-mediaplayer-and-videoview-tutorial) is a full example.
3. A quick and the easiest solution would be to play the video in a WebView. The video is located in the assets folder and by simply open the "file:///android_asset/video.mp4" URL works for me.